# Spyder - An error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gia0f.png)

then I cant install it either

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npsy3.png)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It seems you have an error in the command you wrote in the terminal, which gives the error you show in the second image. In `conda install spyder-kernels=2.1` there needs to be an hyphen (`-`) between `spyder` and `kernels`, but it seems another symbol is in there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had previously installed Python, Pycharm, and Spyder. I deleted Spyder and then installed Anaconda. Received same errors as you. You could try the pip command. However, what fixed it for me was uninstalling everything: Python, Pycharm, and Anaconda. Anaconda requires a restart to completely uninstall. I then reinstalled Anaconda and it was OK.